# Pause and resume animations except of rotation in iOS?

Tags: ios, animation, rotation, core-animation, calayer

If I need simply to pause/resume rotation then I use the following code:

```
- (void)pauseAnimations
{
    CFTimeInterval paused_time = [self.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil];
    self.layer.speed = 0.0;
    self.layer.timeOffset = paused_time;
}

- (void)resumeAnimations
{
    CFTimeInterval paused_time = [self.layer timeOffset];
    self.layer.speed = 1.0f;
    self.layer.timeOffset = 0.0f;
    self.layer.beginTime = 0.0f;
    CFTimeInterval time_since_pause = [self.layer convertTime:CACurrentMediaTime() fromLayer:nil] - paused_time;
    self.layer.beginTime = time_since_pause;
}
```

But I want to stop the current layer animation before rotation and resume after it. And this code stops the rotation process too.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: What do you mean "...stop the current layer animation before rotation and resume after it..."? You want to pause some of the animations you've added to your layer, but want to keep a rotation animation running? And you want your other animations to freeze while your rotation is running, then resume once your rotation animation has completed?

Comment: I need the second one. But as I understand I've already found a places where I need to insert a animation begin/end calls

Comment: I didn't understand your answer at all.

Comment: I'll try again. Question: **I need to freeze all the layer animations except of rotation at the beginning of rotation and resume them at the end of rotation.** As I wrote in my question I have already pasted pause/resume actions in a correct places (starting and ending of rotation) so it seems I have partially answered my main question and so I could ask only for its part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pause a layer's animation's all but one by setting the layer's speed to 0.

You might be able to fetch the active animations from the layer and pause the individual animations using the technique you are using to pause animations on the whole layer (setting the speed to 0).

Note that you can't save a pointer to the animation objects that you create because the system actually adds a copy of the animation to the layer, not the original animation. You would probably need to fetch the animation using the `CALayer` `animationForKey` method.

**Disclaimer:** I have never tried this. My answer is based on general knowledge of how Core Animation works.